# ASP.NET MVC: Routing errors on test server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC3 website for the 1st time. On my development machine everything works fine.

I bin deployed everything on our test machine. After some missing DLL issues the website seemed to work on the following url:

```
http://localhost/Test%20Website
```

But when I clicked the following link (which is created by an inline javascript because I'm using Infragistics Grid which is irrelevant for the question):

```
<a href=\"/Patient/Edit/' + val + '\"><img src=\"../Resources/Edit.png\" align=\"left  \"></a>
```

I get HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found, which is logical, because the Physical Path is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Patient\Edit\537

While the physical Path should be: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test Website\Views\Patient\Edit\537 (atleast... I think... don't understand how MVC routing works exactly)

The links which are made by using the ActionLink HTML helper and such work fine by the way. 
So this works:
    @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
And this works:
    @Html.Partial("Search", new SearchModel())

So, my question is, how do you solve these issues?

p.s.: All the images in resources don't work either. *sigh*

**UPDATE after an answer**

I'm sorry, apparantly it is important to note that this takes place in a javascript function as a string. That's because I'm using the FormatterFunction from Infragistic's JQuery grid. Ok, this is what I've got so far:

```
"function(val) {return '<a href=\"" + @Url.Content("~/Patient/Edit/" + val) + "\"><img src=\"../Resources/Edit.png\" align=\"left\"></a>'; }"
```

The name 'val' does not exist in the current context, which is logical. But I don't know how to solve it, 'cause of my limitted knowledge of javascript/Razor/etc... Could you please help? Val in this case is by the way the value of the column it's bound to. In this case the ID of patient.

**Ego4eg asked more code**

It's Infragistics JQuery grid. This grid has a FormatterFunction which has a string as parameter. This string needs to be a javascript function. To give you an idea, this looks like:

```
@(Html.Infragistics()
.Grid(Model)
.ID("grid1")
.AutoGenerateColumns(false)
.Columns(column => {
    //column.For(p => p.ID).FormatterFunction("function(val) {return '<a href=\"/Patient/Edit/' + val + '\"><img src=\"../Resources/Edit.png\" align=\"left\"></a>'; }").Width("25px").HeaderText(" ");
    column.For(p => p.ID).FormatterFunction("function(val) {return '<a href=\"" + @Url.Action("Edit", "Patient", new { id = val }) + "\"><img src=\"../Resources/Edit.png\" align=\"left\"></a>'; }").Width("25px").HeaderText(" ");
    column.For(p => p.ID).FormatterFunction("function(val) {return '<a href=\"/Home/CreateRemark/?patientID=' + val + '\"><img src=\"../Resources/add.png\" align=\"left\"></a>'; }").Width("25px").HeaderText(" ");
    column.For(p => p.FullName).DataType("string").HeaderText("Naam").Width("250px");
    column.For(p => p.Address).DataType("string").HeaderText("Adres").Width("400px");
    column.For(p => p.BSN).DataType("string").HeaderText("BSN").Width("85px");
    column.For(p => p.DateOfBirthAsString).DataType("string").HeaderText("Geboortedatum").Width("85px");
    column.For(p => p.GeneralPractitionerName).DataType("string").HeaderText("Huisarts");
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use `Url.Content` like:

```
<a href=\"@Url.Content("~/Patient/Edit/" + val)\">
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for answering. I'm at this for a few hours now. 2nd of all, apparantly it IS important that it's in an inline javascript function which is a string, so I updated my question. Hopefully you can help. See updated question at the bottom please.

Comment: I'm confused a bit with your update. I'm not sure where this string is used in your code. Could you provide a more completed example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question with more information. Thank you for sticking with me.

Comment: Try `return '<a href=\"" + @Url.Action("Edit", "Patient") + "/' + val +'\"><img src=\"../Resources/Edit.png\" align=\"left\"></a>';`

Comment: @Egor4eg Thank you so much! I almost had the answer. I forgot to put the +'s around val to concat the string in javascript also ofcourse. May I please ask 1 more question? The links to the .png's (resources) don't work either. Simple adding a tilde didn't work on my developmentmachine. Do you know how I should solve this for the operational server and the developmentmachine?

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan Use the same approach `@Url.Content` for png files as well.

Comment: @Egor4eg Oh yes, ofcourse. Thank you very much. I'll give you the credits now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href ="Url.Action("Edit", "Patient", new { id = val })" />
```

Comment: First of al, thank you very much for replying. Your answer was good also, in the end. But Egor4eg helped me to the final conclusion, so he deserves the credits.